# Caching Zoomable Web Image

Tags: java, android, universal-image-loader, aquery

**Aquery**

*Zoomable Web Image
In addition to ImageView, a WebView can be used to display an image along with Android build in zoom support for WebView. Image will be centered and fill the width or height of the webview depending on it's orientation.*

I using,

```
        String url1 = "file:///mnt/sdcard/image.jpg";
            aq.id(R.id.webView1).progress(R.id.progress).webImage(url1);
```

---

I noticed that even if I cut off the connection and re-open that application, the image is still displayed. Is it cached? I looked into its sd card folder, nothing there. I'd like to utilize cached images instead of fetching it many times.

Also, I am both using Universal-Image-Loader and Android Query. I am just concern if they can both read cached images.

```
       //Aquery
       //returns the cached file by url, returns null if url is not cached
       File file = aq.getCachedFile(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

The url1 is being downloaded every time you call 
  aq.id(R.id.webView1).progress(R.id.progress).webImage(url1);

Your cached file is being returned to File file object but you arent making use of it in